# NotSerializableException(UpdateHandler)

Tags: java, swing, rmi, notserializableexception

I wrote a GUI which connects with a server application using RMI. Because the GUI has to show the online users a thread refreshes the JLabel which includes the "Online-User-List". Sometimes I get this exception on runtime:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler


at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3697)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

...

The exception appears here:

```
try {
        onlineUser = Client.getInstance().connect().GetOnlineUser();
    } catch (RemoteException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();

    }
```

in this methode:

```
public void lookForPlayers() {
    this.getPanel_2().removeAll();
    List<User> onlineUser = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        onlineUser = Client.getInstance().connect().GetOnlineUser();
    } catch (RemoteException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();

    }
    int i = 5;
    for (User user : onlineUser) {
        if (!(user.getID_user().equals(Client.getInstance().getUser()
                .getID_user()))) {
            JLabel lbltest = new JLabel(user.getID_user());
            lbltest.setBounds(10, i, 121, 14);
            this.getPanel_2().add(lbltest);
            i = i + 17;
        }

    }
    this.getPanel_2().repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I use this Methode in a Timer-inner-class:

```
private class Prozess extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {

        lookForPlayers();
        checkEinladungen();
        checkBestätigung();

    }
}
```

This is the class which has the Timer-inner-class (most of them is GUI):

```
package ch.berufsbildungscenter.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import ch.berufsbildungscenter.rmi.Client;
import ch.berufsbildungscenter.rmi.User;

public class LogedInWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3892660882088306231L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 1);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18);
    FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(font);
    JButton b = new JButton(new ImageIcon("/recources/images/button.png"));
    private JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    private JButton btnPaddleWhlen = new JButton("Paddle w\u00E4hlen");
    private User users = new User();
    private String chal;
    private JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    private JTextField textArea = new JTextField();
    private JButton btnAbmelden = new JButton("Abmelden");
    private Timer timer;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public LogedInWindow(User u) {

        this.setTimer(new Timer());
        this.getTimer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Prozess(), 0, 10);

        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 450);
        setResizable(false);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.getBtnPaddleWhlen().addActionListener(this);
        this.getOk().addActionListener(this);
        this.getBtnAbmelden().addActionListener(this);
        timer = new Timer();

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 0, 364, 44);
        contentPane.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblAngemeldetAls = new JLabel("Angemeldet als:");
        lblAngemeldetAls.setBounds(0, 18, 100, 33);
        lblAngemeldetAls.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel_1.add(lblAngemeldetAls);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(u.getID_user());
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(102, 18, 150, 33);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(font);
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblOnline = new JLabel("Online");
        lblOnline.setBounds(260, 11, 46, 14);
        panel_1.add(lblOnline);

        panel_1.add(b);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(LogedInWindow.class
                .getResource("/images/button.png")));
        lblOnline.setBounds(270, 11, 46, 14);
        btnNewButton_1.setBorder((BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15,
                15)));
        btnNewButton_1.setBorderPainted(true);
        btnNewButton_1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnNewButton_1.setFocusPainted(false);

        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    e.getWindow().dispose();
                    Client.getInstance().connect().logout(Client.getInstance());
                } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(275, 7, 89, 23);
        panel_1.add(btnNewButton_1);

        this.getPanel_2().setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        this.getPanel_2().setBounds(212, 79, 162, 201);
        this.getPanel_2().setLayout(null);
        contentPane.add(this.getPanel_2());

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setBounds(10, 291, 364, 42);
        contentPane.add(panel_3);
        panel_3.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnShop = new JButton("Shop");
        btnShop.setBounds(0, 11, 80, 23);
        panel_3.add(btnShop);

        JButton btnPaddleWhlen = new JButton("Paddle w\u00E4hlen");
        btnPaddleWhlen.setBounds(110, 11, 122, 23);
        panel_3.add(btnPaddleWhlen);

        JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
        panel_4.setBounds(10, 344, 364, 57);
        contentPane.add(panel_4);
        panel_4.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblChallange = new JLabel("Challenge: ");
        lblChallange.setBounds(10, 11, 86, 14);
        panel_4.add(lblChallange);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Rangliste");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(251, 0, 113, 23);
        panel_4.add(btnNewButton);
        textArea.setBounds(106, 11, 100, 15);
        panel_4.add(textArea);

        ok.setBounds(106, 34, 80, 23);
        panel_4.add(ok);

        btnAbmelden.setBounds(251, 34, 113, 23);
        panel_4.add(btnAbmelden);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panel.setBounds(10, 79, 179, 201);
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblCoins = new JLabel("Coins:");
        lblCoins.setBounds(10, 11, 121, 14);
        panel.add(lblCoins);

        JLabel lblPunkte = new JLabel("Punkte:");
        lblPunkte.setBounds(10, 36, 121, 14);
        panel.add(lblPunkte);

        JLabel lblGewonneneSpiele = new JLabel("Gewonnene Spiele:");
        lblGewonneneSpiele.setBounds(10, 63, 121, 14);
        panel.add(lblGewonneneSpiele);

        JLabel lblGespielteSpiele = new JLabel("Gespielte Spiele:");
        lblGespielteSpiele.setBounds(10, 88, 121, 14);
        panel.add(lblGespielteSpiele);

        JLabel lblWinlose = new JLabel("Win/Lose:");
        lblWinlose.setBounds(10, 113, 121, 14);
        panel.add(lblWinlose);

        JButton btnSpielstatistik = new JButton("Spielstatistik");
        btnSpielstatistik.setBounds(10, 167, 121, 23);
        panel.add(btnSpielstatistik);

        JLabel lblPaddle = new JLabel("Paddle:");
        lblPaddle.setBounds(10, 138, 121, 14);
        panel.add(lblPaddle);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("" + u.getGeld());
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(133, 11, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("" + u.getRankedPunkte());
        label.setBounds(133, 36, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("" + u.getGewonneneSpiele());
        label_1.setBounds(133, 61, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label_1);

        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("" + u.getGespielteSpiele());
        label_2.setBounds(133, 88, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label_2);

        JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("" + u.getWinLose());
        label_3.setBounds(133, 113, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label_3);

        JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("" + u.getSelectedPaddle());
        label_4.setBounds(133, 142, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label_4);

        JLabel lblStatistik = new JLabel("Statistik");
        lblStatistik.setBounds(10, 55, 73, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblStatistik);

        JLabel lblOnlinePlayers = new JLabel("Online Players");
        lblOnlinePlayers.setBounds(212, 55, 100, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblOnlinePlayers);

    }

    private class Prozess extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {

            lookForPlayers();
            checkEinladungen();
            checkBestätigung();

        }
    }

    public void lookForPlayers() {
        this.getPanel_2().removeAll();
        List<User> onlineUser = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            onlineUser = Client.getInstance().connect().GetOnlineUser();
        } catch (RemoteException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();

        }
        int i = 5;
        for (User user : onlineUser) {
            if (!(user.getID_user().equals(Client.getInstance().getUser()
                    .getID_user()))) {
                JLabel lbltest = new JLabel(user.getID_user());
                lbltest.setBounds(10, i, 121, 14);
                this.getPanel_2().add(lbltest);
                i = i + 17;
            }

        }
        this.getPanel_2().repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void checkEinladungen() {
        Client einlader = Client.getInstance();
        try {
            einlader = Client.getInstance().connect()
                    .checkEinladen(Client.getInstance());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!einlader.getUser().getID_user()
                .equals(Client.getInstance().getUser().getID_user())) {

            int eingabe = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Wollen sie die Herausforderung von "
                            + einlader.getUser().getID_user() + " annehmen?",
                    "Einladung", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (eingabe == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                try {
                    Client.getInstance().connect()
                            .annehmen(Client.getInstance(), einlader);
                    setVisible(false);
                    Client.getInstance().beitreten(Client.getInstance(),
                            einlader);
                    dispose();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void checkBestätigung() {
        Client gegner = Client.getInstance();
        try {
            gegner = Client.getInstance().connect()
                    .checkBestätigungen(Client.getInstance());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!gegner.getUser().getID_user()
                .equals(Client.getInstance().getUser().getID_user())) {

            setVisible(false);
            Client.getInstance().erstellen(Client.getInstance(), gegner);
            dispose();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource().equals(getBtnPaddleWhlen())) {
            new Paddle(users);

        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(getOk())) {
            List<User> onlineUser = new ArrayList<User>();
            this.setChal(textArea.getText());

            try {

                onlineUser = Client.getInstance().connect().GetOnlineUser();

            } catch (RemoteException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            boolean exist = false;
            for (User u : onlineUser) {
                if (this.getChal().equals(u.getID_user())) {
                    exist = true;
                    if (u.getClient().isIngame()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, u.getID_user()
                                + " befindet sich bereits in einem Spiel",
                                "Fehler", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (Client.getInstance().getUser().getID_user()
                            .equals(u.getID_user())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Du kannst dich nicht selber einladen",
                                "Fehler", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Client.getInstance()
                                    .connect()
                                    .einladen(Client.getInstance(),
                                            u.getClient());
                        } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            if (exist == false) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Spieler wurde nicht gefunden!", "Fehler",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(getBtnAbmelden())) {

            try {
                this.dispose();
                Client.getInstance().connect().logout(Client.getInstance());
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }

    public JPanel getPanel_2() {
        return panel_2;
    }

    public void setPanel_2(JPanel panel_2) {
        this.panel_2 = panel_2;
    }

    public JButton getBtnPaddleWhlen() {
        return btnPaddleWhlen;
    }

    public void setBtnPaddleWhlen(JButton btnPaddleWhlen) {
        this.btnPaddleWhlen = btnPaddleWhlen;
    }

    public User getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(User users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getChal() {
        return chal;
    }

    public void setChal(String chal) {
        this.chal = chal;
    }

    public JTextField getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

    public void setTextArea(JTextField textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    public JButton getOk() {
        return ok;
    }

    public void setOk(JButton ok) {
        this.ok = ok;
    }

    public JButton getBtnAbmelden() {
        return btnAbmelden;
    }

    public void setBtnAbmelden(JButton btnAbmelden) {
        this.btnAbmelden = btnAbmelden;
    }

    public Timer getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }

    public void setTimer(Timer timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you call this method?

Comment: Your use of threading is most definitely not safe and flies against Swing threading rules as you appear to be mutating Swing components off of the Swing event thread.

Comment: @The Kanguru how do you start your thread?

Comment: Where is the code that throws this exception; what is it writing when it does so; and where is the definition of that class?

Comment: @EJP I will edit my question with the needed information.

Comment: This is not the needed information. We don't need the source code of `ObjectOutputStream` to be posted here. It is copyright (so I've removed it as a violation of site policy), and also readily availlable. I read it in 1997 and most every year since. What we need is the part of your own source code that throws this exception. I also asked for the class that is being serialized. You haven't posted that either.

Comment: The thread is an inner class in my LoggedInView class. I dont know which part of my sourcecode throws the exception. The exception appears random, sometimes after 10 seconds I use the client application and sometimes after 5 minutes etc. PS: I didn't serializable LoggedInView because it extends JFrame. Sry if I don't understand you.

Comment: **I** know which part of your source code throws the exception. It's right there in the stack trace. Have a proper look. And post the class you were asked to post twice. If you're just going to waste time nobody can help you.

Comment: @EJP add informations.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the Interface `Serializable` on your object `User`. This should fix your Problem.

You can read more about `Serializable` over here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem. He states that his problem is intermittent, and it looks like the exception involves Swing `BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler`, a strange exception. I'm guessing threading issues are involved. It suggests that he's somehow trying to serialize a Swing component, which hopefully he's not doing.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: I am quite sure it is not the problem. Read the exception. The non-Serializable class is named therein.